# Thevenizing a Circuit when current through load is a paramter

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

The question is to find the current i in the following circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flC5iK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**My Attempt:**

I considered \$10\:\Omega\$ resistor as the load.

Finding \$V_{th}\$:

I removed the \$10\:\Omega\$ resistor from the circuit. This makes \$i=0\$. So, the CCCS doesn't supply any current and hence I opened it. The final circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsnEzo.png)</sup>

I calculated \$V_{AB}\$ to be 270 V which would be my \$V_{th}\$.

Finding \$R_{th}\$:

I attached a 1 V Voltage source across AB. Next, I nullified all independent sources and removed the \$10\:\Omega\$ resistor from the circuit. Again, \$i=0\$ and I opened it like before. The circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR4oNQ.png)</sup>

\$R_{th}=\dfrac{1}{i'}\$

\$i'=\dfrac{1}{60}\:A\$

\$\Longrightarrow\:R_{th}=60\:\Omega\$

From the Thevenin Equivalent Circuit, I got the current \$i\$ to be \$\dfrac{24}{7}\:A\$.

And I know this is wrong because I did the same problem using Superposition principle and got the right answer (\$i=1.8\:A\$).

Is there anything wrong with what I did?

Comment: Your error is that you have ignored the CCCS when solving for Rth. To find Rth put a 1A current source instead of a load resistor and turn off all independent sources.

Comment: But isn't that going to be 0? Since i=0? That's why I opened it

Comment: No, because instead of a load resistance you inserted a 1A current source, hence CCCS current becomes 4A.

Comment: I have used a 1V voltage source not current source

Comment: Sure you can use voltage source instead. But even with a 1V voltage source, the CCCS control current is not 0A.

Comment: I was thinking that the CCCS depended on the current through the resistor. Now I realize that it actually depends on the current through the branch AB regardless of any component. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: upvote for putting in the effort on the question ..... i would upvote a second time, if i could, for using circuitlab instead of posting pictures of a book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you've already worked out what went wrong. But nodal is the "go to" approach. (I've grounded the bottom node, mentally, so it's voltage is arbitrarily set to zero.) Nodal analysis has:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_A}{40\:\Omega}+\frac{V_A}{10\:\Omega}&=6\:\text{A}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{40\:\Omega}+\frac{V_B}{10\:\Omega}\\\\
\frac{V_B}{10\:\Omega}+\frac{V_B}{20\:\Omega}&=4\cdot\frac{V_A-V_B}{10\:\Omega}+\frac{V_A}{10\:\Omega}+\frac{-30\:\text{V}}{20\:\Omega}
\end{align*}$$

This is two equations in two unknowns and solves out as \$V_A=168\:\text{V}\$ and \$V_B=150\:\text{V}\$. From that, the current \$i\$ is trivial: \$i=\frac{168\:\text{V}-150\:\text{V}}{10\:\Omega}=1.8\:\text{A}\$.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch!

Me and probably other members who have hanged here a while see that you calculate again with equivalent circuit and derive it again by changing the circuit. It breaks the connection that controls the dependent source.

Use a method which assumes only one unique state for the dependent source through the whole calculation. You can write the voltage between B and the bottom line in two ways. One of them is (6A-i)*40Ohm-i*10Ohm. Marking the voltages equal, you have one equation and one unknown, the wanted i.

ADD

If you for some reason must apply an equivalent, say Thevenin's one, then replace 4i with an unknown current source X. Solve i, use Thevenin's equivalent if you want. Finally you will get i=A+BX, where A is a current value caused by all other sources than X. B is a numerical constant.

Variable X will not vanish, you must bring it along all the time until you have i=A+BX. Now you can write X=4i. Write i=A+4Bi, simplify i=A/(1-4B)

Comment: Why are we making the voltages equal?

Comment: because you express one voltage in two ways to get the equation to be solved. The other way is 5i*20Ohm-30V